# javascript .filter() array not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on an angularjs controller and trying to filter an object and not sure what I am doing wrong here.

I have an object that contains the following:

```
[
    {
    "id": 1,
    "is_new": true,
    "shielded": false,
    "favicon" : "images/favicon.png",
    "created": "2017-10-18T19:15:07.118477Z",
    "email_domain": "domain.com",
    "sender_name": null,
    "sender_email": "xxx@domain.com"
    },{
    "id": 2,
    "is_new": true,
    "shielded": true,
    "favicon" : "images/favicon.png",
    "created": "2017-10-18T19:15:06.765423Z",
    "email_domain": "domain.com",
    "sender_name": null,
    "sender_email": "xxx@domain.com"
    }
]
```

and my controller is this:

```
app.controller('emailController', function($scope, Emails) {
    Emails.getItems().then(function(response) {
        $scope.emails = response.data;
        //$scope.grouped = group($scope.emails);
        $scope.inboxed = inbox($scope.emails);

        /*function group(arr) {
            var grouped = {};
            arr.forEach(item => {
                var grp = item.sender_email[0]
                grouped[grp] = grouped[grp] || [];
                grouped[grp].push(item);
            })
            return grouped;
        }*/

        function inbox(arr) {
            var inboxed = arr;
            inboxed.filter(function(eval) {
                eval.shielded === false;
                console.log(eval.shielded);
                return eval;
            });
            return inboxed;
        }
    })
});
```

and so when I am running this script above, and check in console.lo the function is returning both arrays in the object and not filtering only the array where shielded equals false. Maybe just a syntax error?

Comment: just say var inboxed = arr.filter(function(eval)) and return eval.shielded === false. you don't tell filter what to return, you tell it what to evaluate, so for each item in your array only the items that return true based on your condition (in this case eval.shielded === false) will be returned to your filtered array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is doing the following:

```
function inbox(arr) {
    // create a new variable that refers to the same array as arr
    var inboxed = arr;

    // filter inboxed and do nothing with the filtered result
    inboxed.filter(function(eval) {
        // evaluate eval.shielded === false and do nothing with the result
        eval.shielded === false;
        // log eval.shielded to the console
        console.log(eval.shielded);
        // return eval, which is truthy, so the item being checked will pass the filter
        return eval;
    });

    // return the unmodified array
    return inboxed;
 }
```

What you probably wanted to do was this:

```
function inbox(arr) {
    return arr.filter(function(eval) {
        return !eval.shielded;
    });
}
```

Comment: this is the correct answer , don't filter inboxed though, filter arr and assign it to inboxed

Answer (score 0):

the `filter` function returns a new array that has been filtered, and does not mutate your existing array:

```
function inbox(arr) {
    // return the result of calling filter >>>
    return arr.filter(function(eval) {
        eval.shielded === false;
        console.log(eval.shielded);
        return eval;
    });

}
```

Comment: should return `eval.shielded === false;` or `eval.shielded `

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a syntax error to me - you're returning `eval`, the entry itself, rather than a Boolean. You must return a Boolean value to filter something out. I think everything returns since any value itself is "truthy".

i.e. change it from this:

```
inboxed.filter(function(eval) {
  eval.shielded === false;
  console.log(eval.shielded);
  return eval;
});
```

to something like this:

```
inboxed.filter(function(eval) {
  console.log(eval.shielded);
  return eval.shielded === false;
});
```

Also side note, your `inboxed` variable would still modify `arr` if I'm correct. Better practice would be to `slice` it to create a brand new array and then both can be manipulated without affecting each other.

```
var inboxed = arr.slice();
```

Hope that works!

Comment: `.filter()` doesn't modify the source array. There's no need to slice.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that you're returning `inboxed` It should look something more like this:

```
  function inbox(arr) {
      inboxed == arr.filter(function(eval) {
          eval.shielded === false;
          console.log(eval.shielded);
          return eval;
      });
      return inboxed;
  }
```

You're function will just return the ariginal array, however when you're logging, you're going to see the results you want to see. `filter` doesn't mutate the original array, it executes on the array its called on, but if that return value isn't pointed to by a variable it will immediately be lost after execution.